# raspberry pi A+ boot from usb

Tags: usb

Can RasPi A+ boot from usb?
All the articles I could find only speak about booting from an SD card.

Comment: AFAIK the internal ROM does not support direct booting from USB. But nothing prevents you from puttng a bootloader on the SD that continues its boot from USB. But what does this have to do with Electrical Engineering?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as this belongs in the RPI stack

Comment: It doesn't have a BIOS. Only hardware, that only runs SD Cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to boot from the SD card.

The internal ROM first loads a small boot file (`bootcode.bin`) from the SD card. This then examines the configuration (`cmdline.txt`) and loads the `start.elf` file (which can be specified in cmdline.txt).  That then configures the base system (hardware peripherals etc).  `start.elf` then loads the kernel or another boot manager (such as uBoot).

The closest you can get is to use the SD card to boot the initial system and load the kernel, and have the root filesystem pointing to a USB device.  Step-by-step details can be found here: https://samhobbs.co.uk/2013/10/speed-up-your-pi-by-booting-to-a-usb-flash-drive